# VB.NET - Can't get Integer to work

Tags: vb.net, winforms, integer

I'm working with Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2015, using .NET Framework 4.5.2. So I'm making a simple program which includes a label to display a value. The label (called `lblMoney`) displays the currency (in this case, `$`) and then the value (e.g  `350`). Together it looks like `$350`.

Now, I made another form with a `textbox` called `txtCash` and a `button` called `bApply`. You enter any `integer` (e.g `350`) into `txtCash`. When you press `bApply`, the number in `txtCash` will `add` to the number in `lblMoney`. So, if you had `5` in `lblMoney`, and you entered `350` in `txtCash`, `lblMoney` would display `355`.

Here's my code to `add` to the number:

```
My.Forms.VeilSideCash.lblMoney.Text = cstrx + txtCash.Text.ToString
```

The form `VeilSideCash` is the form that holds `lblMoney`.

Here's the code for `cstrx`:

```
Dim cstrx = "$" & Val(My.Settings.Money.ToString)
```

The problem here is that, instead of `overwriting` to `lblMoney`, the new number is just added after the original number. So if `lblMoney` has `5` and you enter `350` into `txtCash`, `lblMoney` looks like `$5350`.

How would I go about `overwriting` with the new number (`adding` to) instead of `replacing`?

Any help would be appreciated. Feel free to edit incase I messed something up while explaining.

Comment: Please show us  your code instead of describing it.  It's a lot easier to help that way.

Comment: VB won't know what to do with the "$". You need to remove it, convert to an integer, add them together, then convert back to a string.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey How would I go about converting `$` as a string to an integer? Excuse my ignorance..

Comment: Start by turning on Option Strict.  Integers do not have fractional values but Val() always returns `double`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the "$" and convert to a number. I used a decimal so you can include cents if you want:

```
Dim sum As Decimal
sum = Val(cstrx.Replace("$","")) + Val(txtCash.Text)

My.Forms.VeilSideCash.lblMoney.Text = sum.ToString()

Dim cstrx = sum.ToString("C")
```

Note that I used the "C" to format the sum as currency. That automatically puts the $ on for you, or uses other currency symbols for other countries.

I'm not a big VB.net user, so my syntax may be slightly off.

Comment: I included your code in the sub of `bApply`. I have the `Dim cstrx As Double = Val(My.Settings.Money.ToString)` right above `bApply`'s sub. At `cstrx.Replace` I'm getting the error `Local variable 'cstrx' cannot be referred to before it is declared.`. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: cstrx is a double? You cannot store a "$" on a double. cstrx has to be a string.

Comment: keep in mind, I just put the statement in the same order you had them in your question. Yes, you must set cstrx before using it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is the Option Strict setting for your project. You have it set to Off and this allows your code to freely treat strings as they were numbers and try to use them in mathematical operations.

But, when you use the + operator between two strings, it doesn't matter if, for a human being, the two strings represent a number, the compiler see them as strings (cstrx,  txtCash.Text) and thinks that you want to use the concatenation operator defined for strings (the +). Yielding wrong (for you) results .

I really suggest you to not use the automatic conversions made by the compiler on your code, instead, when you need to do math operations, always convert your strings to numbers and do the math with variables of numeric type (You could also change the Option Strict to On, but you should be prepared to solve a lot of problems in your current code)

Instead, with a proper numeric approach, you get the text inside txtCash and try to check if your user has correctly typed a decimal value.

```
Dim cash As Decimal
if Not decimal.TryParse(txtCash.Text, cash) Then
   MessageBox.Show("Invalid cash value")
   Return
End if
```

Now get the text of lblMoney and convert it back to a decimal number alerting the compiler that there is a currency symbol in the text to convert

```
Dim current As Decimal
current = decimal.Parse(lblMoney.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Now you have two numbers and the + operator does what you expect. It adds the two numbers together. Finally you could write back the result with a proper currency formatting

```
Dim result as Decimal
result = current + cash
lblMoney.Text = result.ToString("C")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `+` operator with string unexpected results can occur. In this case the string with a `$` cannot be implicitly converted so you should explicit convert it

Once you convert your strings to a number type you can then use the `+` operator and they can be implicitly converted back to a string.

```
My.Forms.VeilSideCash.lblMoney.Text = decimal.Parse(cstrx, NumberStyles.Currency)  
+ decimal.Parse(txtCash.Text ,NumberStyles.Currency)
```